# Don't know why C# PowerShell Runspace is closing irregularly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, powershell, office365

I have a MVC web application which shows some information about users in our AD. The AD is synchronized with Office 365, so using the UPN I can retrieve the license information from Office 365 using the [Windows PowerShell cmdlets for Office 365](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/hh125002.aspx). Basically this all works fine.

As the initialization cmdlet `Connect-MsolService` takes some time to finish, I'm using kind of a singleton pattern for my `Office365Connector` class. In my `Global.asax` in `Application_Start()` I initialize the singleton instance, in `Application_End()` I dispose it. The connector class uses exactly one instance of my `PowerShellInvoker` class which - as the name implies - encapsulates PowerShell invoking. The PowerShell initialization code inside the `PowerShellInvoker` constructor looks like this:

```cs
public PowerShellInvoker(params string[] modules)
{
    var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    iss.ImportPSModule(modules);
    iss.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true;

    _runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
    _runspace.Open();
    _invoker = new RunspaceInvoke(_runspace);
}
```

The `Office365Connector` class calls this constructor with `"MSOnline"` as parameter. The `MSOnline` module contains the cmdlets for Office 365. I keep the `_runspace` and `_invoker` fields for command execution at a later time. Both fields will be disposed in the `Dispose` method of `PowerShellInvoker` (which is called when the `Office365Connector` class is being disposed). Script execution is done by this line of code:

```cs
_invoker.Invoke(scriptText);
```

So much for the introduction - now here comes the real problem:

In my application, I have a user list. When I click a user, additional information is loaded using an AJAX request. Within this request, my app uses the singleton instance of the `Office365Connector` class to retrieve the license information for the user. In most cases, this all works perfectly. But sometimes the AJAX request ends up with a code 500. Debugging my source code, I stumbled upon an Exception being thrown in the `PowerShellInvoker` on the "Invoke" line above, telling me that the Runspace is not open anymore, and I can't figure out why. I can't even really reproduce it. Sometimes, the error occurs when I click the second user. Sometimes, the error occurs on the 10th or 15th user. I already thought about some weird clean-up, timeout or garbage collection techniques used by MVC, but I haven't come to a conclusion. IMHO, the Runspace closing can't be time-based because the time between the "user clicks" is just a few seconds.

The `Connect-MsolService` cmdlet creates a connection to Office 365, but it doesn't return anything. So re-creating the Runspace if needed is not a work-around because this would be done by the `PowerShellInvoker` class and the `Office365Connector` wouldn't know that it has to reconnect to Office 365. (Also this would not *solve* the problem.) Combining the two classes isn't a solution either because the `PowerShellInvoker` is also used elsewhere.

So can anyone tell me how to prevent the Runspace from closing or why it is closed?

***Edit:*** More code

The full `PowerShellInvoker` class can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Gqd9nMw1).

In the `Office365Connector` class, there is currently much overhead. Here are some snippets:

**Initialization in constructor:**

```
var cred = new PSCredential(adminUpn, adminPassword);

_psi = new PowerShellInvoker("MSOnline");
_psi.ExecuteCommand("Connect-MsolService", new { Credential = cred });
```

**Method to retrieve the license for a UPN:**

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUserLicenses(string upn)
{
    PSObject[] licenses = _psi.ExecuteScript(string.Format("(Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName \"{0}\").Licenses | % {{ $_.AccountSkuId }}", upn)).ToArray();

    // no licenses: a list with one element (which is null) is returned.
    if (licenses.Length == 1 && licenses[0] == null)
    {
        licenses = new PSObject[0];
    }

    return licenses.Select(pso => pso.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

As you can see, I added some `ToList`s to the method return values (especially in the `PowerShellInvoker`). I did this because I wanted to prevent lazy execution of the enumerables because I thought this could be the reason for the closed Runspace.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'd be interested in trying to figure it out. Would it be possible for you to share more code? Also, have you tried starting a PowerShell transcript immediately after opening the runspace? It would be interesting to see if it logged anything useful.

Comment: @ElijahW.Gagne I edited the question and added more code. I will try the transcript idea as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks for the question and answer dude - helped me when trying to write tests for a PS Provider!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this was a stupid mistake by myself - although I don't really understand why MVC is doing this:

In one of my many attempts to solve the problem I moved the disposal code of my `Office365Connector` to the `Dispose` method of the application (in `Global.asax.cs`). After that I apparently fixed the original error but it didn't work out because of the disposal stuff. Apparently the application instance is disposed more often than it is "ended". When I moved the code back to `Application_End()` where it belongs everything worked fine.

That makes my original question kind of invalid because I wrote that my dispose code already was in `Application_End()`. :-\